# What are the best datasets available for music information retrieval?

Tags: natural-language-processing, datasets, data-science, audio-processing, structured-data

I am interested in doing some work in classification problems in music information retrieval. I know that there are some formats of datasets (such as MIDI, Spectrogram, Piano-roll, MusicXML, etc.) for this work but have been unable to find any nice large datasets for this. What are the best free datasets for such work? I am mainly looking into western classical music.